# Один элемент под другим без Position: absolute?

Tags: html, css

Привет, подскажите как сверстать один элемент под другим, что-бы родительский блок сохранил высоту?

Фиддл: http://jsfiddle.net/alpha9000/GEDcH/

P.S. сделал маской прозрачного изображения, мб есть ещё какие варианты?

Comment: а почему нельзя absolute ? ведь у вас родительский div - relative

Comment: схлопывается height у родительского дива а указать прямое значение не представляется возможным

Comment: можно [так](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/GEDcH/5/) но надо знать размеры

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот так можно сделать, через float, не уверен насчет какие браузеры это поддерживают.

```
div {
    position: relative;
    background: #ccc;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 5px;
    z-index: -2;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    float: left; 
    opacity: 0.8;
}
img:nth-child(1n+2) {
    margin-left: -100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/GEDcH/6/

z-index ввел просто чтобы в условие попасть (как я понял вторая должна быть под первой)

Comment: Да именно, margin-left: -100%; оригинальное решение. Спасибо огромное!

Comment: да я сам удивился :) никогда не понимал float :)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/GEDcH/4/

Comment: вы наверно не сохранили результат, фиддл точно такой же как у меня

Comment: сохранил, просто немного не так понял, как вам нужно. посмотрев ответ товарища eicto, я понял что вы имели ввиду =)